# The model doen't fit withTensorflow and Keras Error with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I installed cuda 11.0 and cudnn 8.0 with tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0.
When I fit the model, I get this error.

```
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-23-397fbbe99754>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1671]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I tried to install keras-gpu but the all environment and tensorflow doesn't work.

Comment: Type in `nvidia-smi` on the CLI and verify your cuda version. Then ensure you installed the right version through conda, something like `conda install cudatoolkit=10.1`

Comment: `NVIDIA-SMI 461.40   Driver Version: 461.40   CUDA Version: 11.2`
from tensorflow [versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) I installed like this
`conda install cudatoolkit=11.0 cudnn=8.0 -c=conda-forge` with python3.8

Comment: Do you see the incongruity there? You have CUDA 11.2 but only installed 11.0 on the toolkit.

Comment: How can I replace that I write to install cuda 11.0 in the code
`conda install cudatoolkit=11.0 cudnn=8.0 -c=conda-forge`

Comment: `conda install cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.0 -c=conda-forge`

Comment: The error still exists

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(gpu))
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu[0], True)
```

This solves the error.